# Why do the group members in the local/administrators group have no permissions?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I have added a domain group `local_admins` and domain user `john` to the "local/Administrators" group on the computers in the network through GPO. I want all the users from the domain group to be "local admin" on the computers.

I've confirmed that the group `local_admins` and user `john` is added to the `Administrators` group on the computers on the network with success.

The strange thing is that the users from the domain group `local_admins` have **NO** permissions to do admin actions. But when I try the domain user `john` (which is also in that domain group `local_admins`) then that user **HAS** permissions..

**Situation one, user `john`:**

1. Normal domain user `Jane` (is not in the group `local_admins` and is not in the `Administrators` group) logs in on computer.
2. `Jane` tries to do an admin operation.
3. Windows shows the "Login with admin account" modal.
4. No I fill in the credentials of `john`.
5. ACCESS GRANTED

**Situation two, an user from group `local_admins`:**

1. Normal domain user `Jane` (is not in the group `local_admins` and is not in the `Administrators` group) logs in on computer.
2. `Jane` tries to do an admin operation.
3. Windows shows the "Login with admin account" modal.
4. No I fill in the credentials of `bob` (`bob` is in the `local_admins` group).
5. ACCESS DENIED

I want that all users inside the group `local_admins` are considered `Administrator` on the computers in the domain.

Comment: Users from the group have no admin permission but 'the' user from the group has admin permission? Please make your question more clear.

Comment: @mzhaase Correct,  I updated the question.

Comment: When you added the local_admins group, did you do domain-name\local_admins or just local_admins?

Comment: @mzhaase with the domain prefix. I selected the group and user through the "select user, computer or group" option and searched the domain. Also in the overview I see the domain prefix present. And when I try to add it on the computer by hand then I get the message that the group is already present.

Comment: Can you check whether the gpo go applied correctly? `gpresult /SCOPE COMPUTER /R` or check the local users and groups. While in local users and groups, can you confirm that the members of the local_admin group are resolved?

Comment: @mzhaase In the output I see that the GPO rule is applied. Also I have checked the local users and groups and see that the group `domain\local_admins` is added to the local group `Administrators`. Or do you mean something else with resolved users?

Comment: If you double click on the local_admins group, are all the users listed?

Comment: @mzhaase I can't double click the group `domain\local_admins` listed in the properties modal's members list of the local group `Administrators`. I see the group but there is no action to open that group.

Comment: It's a domain group so check the group membership from the ADUC console on a DC.

Comment: Is a SID shown for the `local_admins` group in the "New Local Group Properties" dialog when you're in the Group Policy Editor editing the policy to add this group to the Administrators group?